# Calibration print shape

Tags: calibration

To check my leveling etc. is correct I was going to print a wide and thin cube.  My theory being that I should be able to spot any obvious separation of the layers.

Does anyone have any better shape that they print as a dry run?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your calibration shape depends on what you want to calibrate on. Among the most popular:

- Benchy as a general "overall" test.
- Lattice Cubes for retraction/stringing and overall quality.
- Two pillars to test for stringing and temperature/cooling control.
- Spikes for retraction, stringing and temperature/cooling control.
- Bridges for cooling control.
- Cubes for sizing. They also allow seeing if the printer is skewed in X or Y.
- Circles, crosshairs, and squares of just a couple layers high to determine the correct center of the print area and measure sizing.
- Cylinders in each other to check the achievable resolution and clearance.
- Overhang tests to test just overhangs.
- Temperature towers for temperature and overhang.
- [Impact](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3092557)<sup>1</sup> & [Bend](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3118965) & [Tension](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:483171) test pieces for filament properties - if you have the setups needed.

---

<sup>1 - I couldn't find a proper model for an *ISO 148-1 Charpy pendulum impact test* in thingieverse</sup>

Comment: Great list, although one not mentioned is a calibration square to measure diagonals in order to test the skewness. This is typically a large square only a few layers tall.

Comment: Lots of useful stuff there.  How doe the bridge to test cooling control work though?

Comment: @BanksySan If the bridge fails or sags too much, you need more cooling.

Comment: @Trish and print slower.